Name and author of short fantasy story masquerading as a novel
A couple of my friends recommended this one to me close to 20 years ago, but I forgot the title before I had time to go looking for it, and I'd kind of like to find it.
The book is sized like a fantasy novel.  Probably somewhere between 200 and 400 pages.  It starts out with the typical "Kill Foozle" plot where a small band of adventurers decide to take out the local "evil wizard."
I know, really generic description that doesn't narrow things down, does it?  Fortunately things get a lot more distinctive rather quickly.  After the usual party assembly plotlines, they get a lucky break and find a trouble-free way into the wizard's lair.  So they charge right in there and confront him.
And he kills them all in a matter of seconds.  At about a quarter of the way through the book.
This is followed by a note from the author explaining that now, whenever you pick up one of his books, the tense scenes will actually be tense.  Because you'll know that everybody really could die.
The rest of the book is a collection of short stories designed to fool anyone who skips ahead into thinking the adventure is on-going.
I think it probably wasn't very widely published, since I can't manage to find any references to it.  But, having only a high-level description to go from, traditional search engines aren't all that helpful.

200 - 400 pages - that narrows it down then.

Nothing in https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SacrificialLamb rings a bell.

@FuzzyBoots i had a go thru most of the Rocks Fall Everyone Dies and related pages.  It feels more like a trolling plot or spoof though. I don't know many authors that could keep readers through that kind of stunt

This is used in Gödel, Escher, Bach as well (in the parts with Achilles and the tortoise), but that's obviously not the answer.

@SolarMike  The two friends who recommended it to me didn't specify an exact length, only that when they first picked it up the size made them assume it was a full novel.

@Radhil  I haven't actually gotten to read it, but if done well, a spoof on all the terrible fantasy novels where the big-bad keeps power despite being horribly incompetent and the "plucky heroes" take him out easily despite having no real experience or even a reasonable plan...  (Or where they fail the first time and are inexplicably allowed to live) could be good, so that may also have been what the author was going for.

@Perkins - so this is all your 20 year old memories of how someone else described this book? The details may be inaccurate?

@ChrisSunami I didn't provide any of the details that I had any doubt about.  It's fantasy genre, the bad guy is a wizard. The presentation of the book makes it look like one, novel-length story when it actually contains multiple, shorter stories. The first story the heroes wade in utterly unprepared and get taken down hard with none of the usual lame escapes that let them come back for round two later. I'm just hoping it's not a case of it having been one of the many regionally-popular authors who live in my corner of the USA that hardly anybody else ever seems to have heard of...
